# How can I split an object property which is a string while using map method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with this data structure -

```
const dummy = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "Print text",
    sequence: "ctrl+p",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "Copy text",
    sequence: "ctrl+c",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: "Paste text",
    sequence: "ctrl+v",
  },
];
```

I want to split the sequence property so that I can get "ctrl", "v" or "ctrl", "c" as separate strings.

The reason for getting this as a separate string because of the UI I have to achieve that is like -
[image]

If we see in the right hand the command key is being displayed with a gap.

If I loop through the existing array using

```
const getSequence = dummy.map((value) => {
  return value.sequence.split("+");
});

console.log("Sequence is" + getSequence[1]);
```

I do get access to the entire string as a whole also it's static.

```
<div className="keys_container" style={{ ...textStyle }}>
  {searchResult.map((value) => {
    return (
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
      <div className="hotkeys" style={{ ...textStyle, paddingBottom: "8px" }}>
        <Icon icon={value.icon} />
        <div>{value.label}</div>
        <div>{value.sequence}</div>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>;
```

I am looping the array here so that the listing shows the dynamic command string but then again it's as a whole.
**i.e "ctrl+v" not "ctrl" + "v" + "anyotherkey"**

Would appreciate it if anyone can just guide me to the logic and I can code it myself. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got all of the pieces you need to make this work, so kudos on getting that far. If I understand the problem correctly, what's missing is something that looks like the invocation of your function inside of your JSX.

Try looking at the div that has {value.sequence} and consider how that variable is going to be expressed differently from what you're passing in to the console.log after the getSequence declaration -

The best way I can think of to explain it is to think about what you're getting back when you call the function, or maybe consider it as a placeholder for what you're getting back. So, value.sequence.split("+") returns an Array, which means you can use Array methods on it. I *think* what you want to do from there is .map over that Array and the .map() callback should return your div with the split section of the string.

---

```
{value.sequence.split("+").map(sequenceSection => <div>{sequenceSection}</div>}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the suggestion. I went ahead and created a custom component and passed the string prop.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom component that accepted the string coming from object property through map() and returning JSX element with split() function.

```
const KeyBind = ({ sequence }) => {
        const keys = sequence.split('+');
        return (
            <div className="command_container">
                <span className="command">{keys[0]}</span>
                <span className="command">{keys[1]}</span>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Final return code

```
<div className="keys_container" style={{ ...textStyle }}>
                {searchResult.map((value) => {
                    return (
                        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
                        <div onClick={value.onClick} className="hotkeys" style={{ ...textStyle, paddingBottom: '8px' }}>
                            <Icon size={12} icon={value.icon} />
                            <div>{value.label}</div>
                            <KeyBind sequence={value.sequence} /> // getting string for each object dynamically
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
```

[image]